# Blender 2.8: How to output renderings in real time just like what is shown in the viewport?

Tags: scripting, 3d-view, export, eevee-render-engine, image

I just was able to start up Blender 2.8 with some of the example projects on the website, and I'm able to pan around and see the real-time render in the viewport, but how can I OUTPUT this real-time render to a PNG sequence?

SO: How can I render IN REAL TIME (almost at least), the same thing I see in the viewport, as an output of PNG files ? (NOT the simple <kbd>F12</kbd> way unless there's a way to majorly speed that up)

I saw some library of gpu background rendering.

**If anyone has any code or anything that at least allows me to get the pixels in rgba format and pass each frame to a background promise queue in real time, then I can figure out png encoding from there.**

Important note: the expected output should be in 1080x1920 (or whatever is specified in the output settings) resolution, based off of the camera position, regardless of whatever the 3d view is currently scaled to.

If it's following the camera, then it should output only what the camera sees. If it's just freeform moving around, it should output the screen at the same resolution.

Comment: I have no clue how to do it in Blender. But I would screen record in fullscreen mode

Comment: @MartinZ BTW I found the answer its under view -- viewport render.

Comment: I don't think there's any avoiding the time it takes your OS to write a file, unless someone can think of a way of writing to a  (potentially huge) memory-buffer.

Comment: @RobinBetts hi. The main thing is to bee able to get the rgba pixel data on real time. Once we have that w can encode it in a separate thread or something. Maybe A custom render engine

Answer (score 2):

I think what you might want is to go to 3d viewport -> click on "View" and "Viewport Render Animation"

Comment: Yes Ive been doing that, but even that is extremely slow relative to the actual viewport

Comment: Well, I don't know of any other option, probably only with a script

Comment: yes ive been trying to make that script https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/128174/python-get-image-of-3d-view-for-streaming-realtime-eevee-rendering

Answer (score 1):

What you might want to try is to render it using Eevee. You select Eevee as render engine and then you can render your sequence as you would in cycles, just in real-time (or close to it).

Comment: Dude that's what I've been trying to do the whole time... It's true that EEVEE renders in the VIEWPORT in real time, but I need a real time OUTPUT, that's the whole question; realtime viewing is worthless if you can't actually save it (in 1920 by 1080, meaning not just "recording" the screen..)

Answer (score 0):

Press  <kbd>Z</kbd> and select rendered to see the image rendered on the viewport

Comment: This is not exactly what the author is asking for.

Comment: quote: *"but how can I OUTPUT this real-time render to a PNG sequence?"*

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so your question isn't very clear, however here are two answers:
If you are looking to render things as they appear in the viewport, set your rendering engine to workbench.

and 2. If you are looking to save an animation path while you move around in your viewport, select the camera, then enable autokeying and move the camera around.

oh also three:
if you want to render where the camera is, go into your camera view and press n. then press view. then check camera to view. now you can move the camera around like how you would move around yourself when modeling in the viewport. then just press f12.

if none of these answer your question, then please restate your question.

Comment: Hi. No. The workbench render is 1) too slow 2) no textures. I'm asking to see the exact same result that can play real-time in the rendered mode in the viewport, at 1080/1920